# Startup with high traffic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

I have just converted my current MVC site to aspnet core. My site is having huge traffic. But i am facing one strange problem in deployment

I am using VS 2017 to publish my core 1.1 site. If i copy all the publish content to site folder and start the site then no request is being served and i am getting "502.3- bad gateway" error. I have checked perfmon and "Active Request" count is only incrementing, goes upto 3000 in a minute. But if i remove site binding and hit the url with one user and then add the site binding then site is working fine without any problem

So this lead to me that starting site with high traffic is causing problem. Is there any setting to avoid this? This is my first core project so I am not aware about it much. I read that kestrel is handling the requests from IIS. Does kestrel is not responding initially? If Kestrel crashes will it be up automatically? Is there way to see kestrel activity?

I am using below code to start my site

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel((options) =>
        {
            options.ThreadCount = 1000;
        })
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()

        .Build();




        host.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but I don't see a call to UseStartup to configure your startup class and configure the application.  You're not configuring how the application responds to HTTP requests in any of that code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup